# Use arguments for drupal views 3

Tags: views

How do you structure and use arguments in a view using the Views UI in Views 3

Comment: This is a very vague question. Can you give some more background or details. If you just need to learn how to use arguments in views install the advanced_help module and it will give you access to the views documents. Also if you do some research you will find tons of docs and videos.

Comment: what I am trying to do is create a block with dynamic information of profile2 fields. I am trying to set the default argument to a specific profile id or taxonomy in the profile fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments in Drupal 7 are the same as contextual filters. Contextual filters are associated with the path of the view (or the view's page). With these, we give a basic determining factor as to how we want to narrow down the view's output. It can be set up on what ever you want it to be. One of the simple ways to do it is by content type or user name. 
Check out this page it explains it well. http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-attachments.
I also found these vids while searching  on relationships and contextual filters (arguments). Check them out they put a lot of things in perspective and teach you how to use them both.

Drupal 6:
http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-relationships 
http://drewish.com/node/127

Drupal 7:
http://vimeo.com/22100751